# Tengo un error al hacer una consulta con hibernate en JSF en un logueo con tablas relacionales

Tags: jsf, hibernate

Errores que me llaman la atencion pero no se como resolverlos

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
11-Jun-2017 21:43:39.164 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-112] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{loginFormBean.searchUser()}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginFormBean.searchUser()}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)


Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:400)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
at aplicacion.hibernate.config.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
... 45 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for agente in class aplicacion.modelo.dominio.CargoDeclarado
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:310)
at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:304)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:323)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:411)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:200)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
```

Hibernate Util

```
package aplicacion.hibernate.config;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
* Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory object.
 *
 * @author Trabajo Y Estudio
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("/aplicacion/hibernate/config/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

private User user;
private UserDAO userDao;
public LoginBean() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    userDao = new UserDAOImp();
}

public String searchUser(String username, String pass) {
    String word = null;
    user = userDao.searchUser(username, pass);
    if (user == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Atencion", "Uasuario No Encontrado"));
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().put("user", user);
        word = "menu?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    return word;
}

public User sessionUser(){
    User user2 = (User)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("user");
    return user2;
}

/**
 * @return the user
 */
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

/**
 * @param user the user to set
 */
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

/**
 * @return the userDao
 */
public UserDAO getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}

/**
 * @param userDao the userDao to set
 */
public void setUserDao(UserDAO userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}

}
```

xml creado por defecto de mapeo y clase de hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 11/06/2017 21:26:05 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class catalog="ddjj" name="aplicacion.modelo.dominio.User" optimistic-lock="version" table="users">
<id name="username" type="string">
  <column length="25" name="username"/>
  <generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name="password" type="string">
  <column length="45" name="password" not-null="true"/>
</property>
<property name="name" type="string">
  <column length="45" name="name" not-null="true"/>
</property>
<property name="lastname" type="string">
  <column length="45" name="lastname" not-null="true"/>
</property>
<property name="sex" type="char">
  <column length="1" name="sex" not-null="true"/>
</property>
<property name="tel" type="string">
  <column length="45" name="tel"/>
</property>
<set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="agenteses" table="agentes">
  <key>
    <column length="25" name="usuario_username" not-null="true"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="aplicacion.modelo.dominio.Agente"/>
</set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

clase creada por defecto de hibernate

```
public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private String username;
 private String password;
 private String name;
 private String lastname;
 private char sex;
 private String tel;
 private Set agenteses = new HashSet(0);

public User() {
}


public User(String username, String password, String name, String lastname, char sex) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.sex = sex;
}
public User(String username, String password, String name, String lastname, char sex, String tel, Set agenteses) {
   this.username = username;
   this.password = password;
   this.name = name;
   this.lastname = lastname;
   this.sex = sex;
   this.tel = tel;
   this.agenteses = agenteses;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return this.lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public char getSex() {
    return this.sex;
}

public void setSex(char sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}
public String getTel() {
    return this.tel;
}

public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}
public Set getAgenteses() {
    return this.agenteses;
}

public void setAgenteses(Set agenteses) {
    this.agenteses = agenteses;
}




}
```

llamado a la consulta busqueda de usuario

```
public class UserDataSource implements Serializable {

public static void add(User user) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

public static void upDate(User user) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

public static User searchUser(String username, String pass) {
    User user = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("username", username))
            .add(Restrictions.like("password", pass));
    System.out.println("Dentro de la busqueda");
    System.out.println(criteria.list().isEmpty());
    if (!criteria.list().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Dentro del if");
        user = (User) criteria.list().get(0);
    }
    session.close();
    return user;
}

}
```

Comment: genial ahora funciona todo gracias

Comment: De nada. Lo dejo como respuesta entonces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cierto punto hibernate invoca a `EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer` el cual trata de crear una instancia de `aplicacion.modelo.dominio.CargoDeclarado`, y en ese proceso invoca los getters de los miembros de esa clase, entre ellos `agente` y no lo encuentra. De allí surge el [PropertyNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException.html)

Lo puedes solucionar agregando el metodo público `getAgente()` en tu clase `CargoDeclarado`

Habiendo solucionado eso volver a ejecutar el código para determinar si el resto de las excepciones estaban relacionadas.